# Could not find json-2.6.2, aws-partitions-1.594.0, unf_ext-0.0.8.2 in any of the sources

Tags: json, rubygems, bundle, fastlane, gemfile

when I execute: bundle exec fastlane

I get: Could not find json-2.6.2, aws-partitions-1.594.0, unf_ext-0.0.8.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

although I am using the current json version, does anyone know how to solve the problem?